# Excel from Google Docs read and save data in SQL Server database using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

The Data shown in excel from google docs insert in Sql server table shown in image
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIsWY.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster doesn't appear to have attempted any solution to the problem on their own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the data first from google sheet. Then Insert it in your database.You can start from here
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet